# Favorite things about Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, gaming-the-system

I enjoy a great many things about Stack Overflow, but you know Stack Overflow works when I caught myself trying to "time-attack" to see if I could score first!

What Stack Overflow trait do you appreciate the most?

Answer (score 7):

The key is to provide the short answer first.

Edit: then edit and give the long answer with **all** the *fancy* `markup`.

```
System.out.println("and code examples!");
```

Comment: Do the edit fast enough and it looks like you had it there from the start, too :)